# Failure when lein run command raises exception from an xterm

Tags: ubuntu, clojure, leiningen

nOOb level -

I cannot get this to run. The dependencies are to be downloaded first and then it should jump to -main (is my understanding).

the project.clj is:

```
(defproject todo-list "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"   
 :description "FIXME: write description"   
 :url "http://example.com/FIXME"   
 :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
        :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}     
:dependencies [
              [org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
              [ring "1.4.0"]
              [compojure "1.3.4"]
              ]
:main todo-list.core
:profiles {:dev
         {:main todo-list.core/-dev-main}}
```

The error message is:
Could not transfer artifact org.clojure:clojure:pom:1.8.0 from/to central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
....etc
....etc

Could not transfer artifact clojure-complete:clojure-complete:pom:0.2.4 from/to central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
This could be due to a typo in :dependencies or network issues.
If you are behind a proxy, try setting the 'http_proxy' environment variable.

I have looked other solutions however none seem to apply.

Since I am on Ubuntu 15.10 in an xterm on a home network without a ad-blocker using a UniFi EdgeRouter providing my connection.
I do not have a configured firewall on PC.

Same problem when I use "lein deps"

BTW my OSX installation works fine and I have mirrored the same codebase to Ubuntu.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What java version are you using on Ubuntu? Please, provide output of `java -version` command.

Comment: openjdk version "1.8.0_66-internal

Comment: BTW I have removed the above latest version of openjdk and reinstalled it - just in case something was dinged. However, same result.

Comment: I also copied the .m2 files from my OSX to insert these into the .m2 repositories on the Ubuntu but same error

Answer (score 3):

I have the solution:
if you are using java 7 or java 8 on Ubuntu and have similar problems as described above then refer to this page - [stackoverflow] ([Getting an exception when trying to run lein](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306345/getting-an-exception-when-trying-to-run-lein?rq=1))
and at xterm do the following:

"sudo -i"
enter your PWD

cut 'n paste this - "/var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst configure"

and done!

The underlying issue Ubuntu did not include the links to java in the certs area.

Solved! All cre3dit goes to the IRC #clojure guys!